How to know what size diode to use for inductive spiking?
I am making a simple Zener flyback circuit for an inductor.
What current rating should the diodes be sized for? Could I use a 1 watt Zener diode because the voltage spike only lasts a few microseconds, or would I have to use a 666 ampere diode? (I = V/R [666 = 66.6/.1])
I currently have a 10 ampere silicon diode and a 1 watt Zener. I have a feeling they will be damaged very quickly, though. Can Zener diodes be put in parallel to split the current?
Here is the circuit I'm using:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

How much current will you have through the inductor?  666 amperes would blow the transistor, never mind the diode(s.)

You will need a pull down resistor on the gate of the MOSFET to turn off the current when you open the switch.

The Q&As in the "Related" section over on the right on this page could be very useful to you.

The mosfet I'm actually using is IRFB4115pbf which can handle 420 amperes pulsed (Two in parallel, 840 ampere). This mosfet wasn't in the circuit simulator.

Added pulldown resistor^

Are the gate resistors actually chained like that?

No. Mistake fixed^

Your MOSFETs are rated for 150V and they will see  217V even if the Zener clamps at exactly 150V at whatever current (it won't). I think you'll have SOA problems too. Lots of fried MOSFETs.

You really should look into Transorbs for this, acronym TSB.  Although they have a power ratings, they are designed for short duration surge events.  Incidentally they are available in both unipolar and bipolar configurations.

Ok, I'll take a look

Is it the same as a TVS diode?

Yes.  Transient Voltage Suppression

They've already found this, or of a sort -- common TVS diodes are just large zeners with peak ratings.

The diode needs to be able to handle the current that is flowing through the inductor when the transistor is conducting. This is because the current through an inductor can't change abruptly.
However it's not entirely clear how big that current actually is in your application. Judging from your schematic and the front page RDSon of the transistor alone, the current would be 66.6V/10.5mOhm =~ 6kA, which is way above the rated current of the transistor (and the diodes).

The coil is only pulsed once for 11ms. I'm also using two 420 ampere mosfets in parallel. Il'l change the schematic above^
